# How can I tweak Google Map Toolbar to fire "generic" intent - Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, android-mapview, android-maps-v2

I've implemented Google Maps in my app to show toolbar with navigation buttons.

Docs:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/controls#map_toolbar

[image: Toolbar]

But it is firing specific Google Maps's intent.

Could I tweak it to fire "Generic" intent so user could choose navigation app of their choice?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You have no control over the ***Map Toolbar***. According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/controls#toolbar) (emphasis mine):

> The toolbar displays icons that provide access to a map view or directions request **in the Google Maps mobile app**

If you want to launch your own Intent you will need to disable this toolbar doing `googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);` and then implement your own `GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener` to show your custom buttons.

---

A workaround (but an ugly one) could be finding the Google Map Directions Button (with the `GoogleMapDirectionsButton` tag) and overwrite it's functionality. Here is a working example:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);

        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(40.42, -3.7), 17));
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(40.42, -3.7)));

        googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
                View v = findGoogleMapDirectionsButton(mapFragment.getView());
                if (v != null) {
                    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(final View view) {
                            final LatLng targetLatLng = new LatLng(
                                    marker.getPosition().latitude,
                                    marker.getPosition().longitude);
                            final Intent intent = new Intent(
                                    Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                    Uri.parse("google.navigation:q="
                                            + targetLatLng.latitude
                                            + ","
                                            + targetLatLng.longitude));
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            MapsActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private View findGoogleMapDirectionsButton(View v) {
        View directionsButton = null;

        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
            for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
                directionsButton = findGoogleMapDirectionsButton(vg.getChildAt(i));
                if (directionsButton != null) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else if (v.getTag() != null
                && "GoogleMapDirectionsButton".equalsIgnoreCase(v.getTag().toString())) {
            directionsButton = v;
        }

        return directionsButton;
    }
}
```